# Can I replace a capacitor with one of lower voltage?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, capacitor, maximum-ratings

I have broken power supply for PC, 400W. A capacitor has failed. I don't have the same capacitor. The one I want to replace is 220μF 25V, and the one that I have to replace it with is 220μF 16V. Would there be any problem with this?

Comment: I've edited assuming those are microfarads, not millifarads. If I'm in error, please correct.

Comment: Also, w is not the same as W.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capacitor's voltage rating is a very tricky thing. In the event of overvoltage, electrolytics like to fail rather unfortunately. It may simply cause physical electrolyte leakage that renders the cap inoperable. That's why these components are *[derated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derating)* in the design stage.

However, since your cap is probably on the 12 Volt rail, there's still a 4-Volt margin. Not much if you ask me (switch mode spikes might be dangerously close to 16V).

Another thing to consider is the [ESR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) rating. Power supplies are very often relying on *low-ESR* capacitors. Pushing more current through "regular" caps may/will degrade their lifespan.

---

I'd just go to your nearest electronics supplier and get a 25V lowish-ESR cap.

Comment: Ok, I have another capacitor that is for 63V but its 330mF would be any problem there? Also the shop is far away from me.

Comment: Use the 63V cap then. And btw, you probably mean 330uF, not mF. That would be a quite a beast.

Comment: LOL yeah, I just realize what I have type. Anyway thank you

Comment: @Dzarda I have a 450V 10mf capacitor and its the size of my forearm :)

Answer (score 6):

You absolutely *should not* replace an electrolytic capacitor with one of lower voltage rating. That would only be okay if the system was designed with a *lot* of overhead, but for high-volume devices like PC power supplies that's very unlikely. You'll likely end up putting more voltage on your replacement capacitor than it was designed to handle, which could cause a small explosion or a fire.