# Using capacitor with lower voltage than the specified one

Tags: capacitor

I'm just a hobbyist and I'm planning to build [this circuit](http://www.redcircuits.com/Page181.htm). It recommends to use a 33pF 63V capacitor. I'm in trouble to find a capacitor with this specific voltage. I only found a 33pF 50V one.

Since the power supply will be 20V, a lower voltage capacitor should not be a problem, right? What kind of problem I will have if I use a 33pF 50V instead of a 63V?

Searching the forum, I found [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103597/can-i-replace-a-capacitor-with-one-of-lower-voltage), but it has two answers and each one points to one direction...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct.  Generally speaking, capacitors must not be subjected to voltages higher than what they are specified for.  In practice, one always chooses a capacitor with voltage rating somewhat in excess of the highest voltage the capacitor might be exposed to.  For example, I would choose a 63V capacitor for a circuit running at 45V.

Your circuit is running at plus minus 20V.  A capacitor voltage rating of 25V is marginal, so I would choose a capacitor voltage rating at 35V or more.  Your 50V capacitor will be just fine.

Comment: Also check the manufacturers derating figures as the voltage withstand decreases with temperature